# Accessing google datastore rest api using api key

Tags: google-apis-explorer

When I try to use the datastore reset api with an api key I get this:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}
```

}

My url looks like this:
    https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{my_project_id}:beginTransaction?key={my_api_key}

In the documentation you get the option of using oauth or api key, but I cant see any way to input an api key on that page:
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/projects/beginTransaction

How do I use my api key to access the datastore api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API keys are not authentication, they are just authorization. The datastore API requires both authentication and authorization to call. In other words, it needs to know *who* you are, not just that you are *allowed* call that API. It uses this information about *who* you are to verify you are allowed to access the specific data you are trying to access. Otherwise, anyone with permission to call the datastore API could access anyone else's datastore data.

As such, you need to use OAuth2 authentication, not API keys (authorization). See **Authorization scopes** on that reference page for more information.

Note that the "Try this API" tool is just helping you learn about how the API works, not forcing you to always do the right thing, that's why it allows you to choose to only use an API key.